# Are there rules for "IRL" diseases?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, d20-system, disease

**Scenario**

I have a particular player that insists that the only place he ever visits in towns/cities are brothels. While this makes for funny role-playing at times, it often splits up the party when I would rather this not happen.

**Question(s)**

Are there supplements (possibly 3rd-party) available for [sexually transmitted disease](http://www.cdc.gov/std/)? And even broader, are there supplements for "everyday" illnesses such as [influenza](http://www.cdc.gov/flu/), the [common cold](http://www.cdc.gov/Features/Rhinoviruses/index.html), and etc?

**Note**

I would rather try to avoid just calling everything a [Contagion](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/contagion.htm) if I can help it.

Comment: These will probably be from a third party publisher for the reasons outlined [here](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/60171/8610). Is that okay?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Absolutely. I included [d20-system](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/d20-system) due to that expectation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The closest thing that I can provide for you in this answer does not actually cover the "IRL" aspect you seem to be looking for, and for that I apologize. However, I can provide you with resources for these sexually transmitted diseases you may find suitable for your objectives.

For this, we have the ***Book of Erotic Fantasy***, which contains all sorts of shenanigans, including but not limited to sexually transmitted diseases. I advise caution at using this resource, as it can be somewhat graphic, and not everyone wishes to use this kind of content in their game (It's serious business, let me tell you).

The section in question begins near the end of Page 44, with a table on the top half of Page 45, and descriptions which end around halfway through Page 47 (and a graphic image on the bottom of Page 46). Some of these diseases are modeled after real-world ones, some are magical in nature, and some are re-vamps or modifications of pre-existing material.

I must apologize, though. I am not sure if you are looking for a print copy, and if you are I am still not sure if you can find one available. Additionally, this material can be rather intense, and I will say again that it is not suitable for everyone. It's actually kind of embarrassing for me to even be able to answer this the moment I see it.

On-top of that, I cannot think of any material that covers other mundane "IRL" diseases that you are also looking for, and I hope that what I have provided here for you will be satisfying enough until/unless a better answer shows up.

One final note: If anyone wants some brief examples of the material in question, I will be happy to provide some disease descriptions, with some appropriate modifications (I'm honestly not sure if/how the TOS addresses these things, which is why I have been super vague thus far).

Comment: I think it's safe to provide a link to book on [*Amazon.com*](http://www.amazon.com/Book-Erotic-Fantasy-Gwendolyn-Kestrel/dp/097420451X/) and let the reader decide.

Comment: @HeyICanChan That's fair. I've done what I can, at least.

Comment: I have always wondered about allergies such as Poison Ivy; viruses such as the Flu; and so on - in a D&D fantasy setting. I predominately play 3.5e; but I like to have things in print. I try to not _wing it_ as much as I can.

Comment: @Ruut I am sorry that I cannot really help you with finding materials for using real-life mundane diseases in your game.

Comment: @Javelin It's all good. No complaints at all.