# Where does poisonous "oil of taggit" come from?

Tags: dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons, lore, poison

Is there any lore in D&D, whether in 5th Edition or prior, about where the poison "oil of taggit" comes from? What kind of thing is a "taggit"? An animal or plant? A mineral? In 5th Edition, it's listed in the *Dungeon Master's Guide* on page 258, but as far as I can tell, it's been in the game since at least 3rd Edition, and possibly before.

I know what *effect* taggit oil has -- it causes long-term unconsciousness -- but I can't find any information about what it is derived from, nor any etymology that might shed light on the question.

Comment: You may also be interested in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/60142/8610).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by *any lore*? Official sources only?

Comment: @JohnP Toss out whatever you got, man.  I'm mostly interested in official sources but third-party information is worth mentioning as long as it's clearly labeled as such.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### No, there is no official lore

There is a simple mention of the oil of taggit in the 3.0 *Dungeon Masters Guide*, on page 80 as an ingested poison with a save DC of 15. (Note, the poisons entry is on an earlier page, this is the table listing various poisons). As near as I can tell this is the first official mention of taggit as a poison, and there is no origin for it listed, nor can I find any other official source that lists an origin.

Official mentions in various editions with no source (That I have found):

- Powers of Faerun
- Complete Adventurer
- Book of Exalted Deeds
- Dungeon Masters Guide
- Dragon Magazine #349
- Song and Silence
- Lords of Madness
- Enemies and Allies
- Dragon Magazine #131 (Beasts of Aulbesmil)

### Unofficial sources

There is a 3rd party publication by the company "Blue Devil Games", and taggit is listed in their sourcebook on poisons *Poisoncraft: The Dark Art*, on page 87 with taggit root as the source:

> OIL OF TAGGIT*

> ***Steeped taggit root***; gray, odorless oil; hedge root family; ingestion DC 15; none / unconsciousness 1d3 hrs; Craft DC 20; Price 300 gp; Exposure DC 4.

(Emphasis mine)

The * next to the name indicates:

> Additionally, all of the poisons from the DMG appear here, recast using the new rules and fleshed out with greater detail. These entries appear with a * following the name.

Comment: Neither my 1e nor 2e AD&D DMG has it. I am thinking it was new in 3.x

Comment: Okay, so the only description you can find is what somebody published in a third-party book, and appears to have been made up from whole cloth for that publication?